# Running .exe to execute batch file written in Python (Novice Programmer)

Tags: python, batch-file, exe, batch-rename, executives

I wrote a Python script to prompt users for a spreadsheet to rename photos automatically based on the column called "Rename_Code" in the spreadsheet. The column is extracted and saved as a batch file, called "Rename_Code.bat". Below is the script:

```
import pandas as pd from tkinter.filedialog 
import askopenfilename

#prompt user to browser excel sheet and load the spreadsheet in python 
xl = pd.ExcelFile(askopenfilename() , index_col=None)
# load a sheet into a dataframe called df1 
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
# assign "Rename Code" column as rename_col 
rename_col = df1['Rename_Code']
# extract the column and write as a batch file 
rename_col.to_csv('Rename_Code.bat', index=False)

from subprocess import Popen p = Popen("Rename_Code.bat", cwd=r"C:\Users\username\Documents\XXXXX") stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

What I am trying to do is convert this script (in .pyw format) into an .exe so that anyone can use it without having Python installed in their computers. I used py2exe to convert the script. However, it kicked an error when I double clicked on the .exe. It says "Failed to launch application".

I am wondering if there is something wrong with the script. Alternatively, is there a better way to execute this, perhaps with Window Services? If yes, how? I am a novice programmer, most of my learning in programming involves a lot of trial and error and research.

I truly appreciate your feedback and help!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do the file rename in Python? I would avoid batch files like the plague, if it were me. They are so terrible to work with!

Comment: For GUI applications I use pyinstaller, with the flag "--windowed".

Comment: @JonahBishop I am not sure how to do it with Python and automate it as an app. Suggestions?